# TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate) in keras sequential

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sequential

I am currently facing this error while running a pretrained model in spyder.

File "C:\Users\catch\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 490, in from_config

TypeError: object.**new**() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2X8m.png)
Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the line of code at line 490 of `sequential.py` ?

Comment: You need to include your code that produces this error, along with the full traceback, all as text (not images).